# TypeError: conv2d(): argument 'padding' (position 5) must be tuple of ints, not str

Tags: python, pytorch

I created following conv layer:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
in_channels = 1
out_channels = 3
kernel_size = 2
conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding='same')
```

After calling this layer I get the following error:

```
TypeError: conv2d(): argument 'padding' (position 5) must be tuple of ints, not str
```

PyTorch Version: 1.7.0 (in kaggle notebook)

Comment: Not supported in [`pytorch 1.7.0`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.0/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html?highlight=nn%20conv2#torch.nn.Conv2d). I think it was added in `pytorch 1.9.0`.

Comment: The handling of `padding='same'` is mentioned in the [1.9.0 release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.9.0).